# Verifying QCheckBox stateChanged?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Forgive me, for I know this is likely to be a very simple question, but I need another set of eyes. I've got a Checkbox on my GUI, and the state of the box (on/off) will directly alter my interrupt service routine. This seems super-easy, but I cannot use:

```
this->ui->checkBox_2->isChecked();
```

as a validator, because of the "invalid use of "this" is non-member function"
beyond that, I've attempted to just save the value of stateChanged(int arg1)
to some pointer or variable that I can call withing my ISR, but I suppose I'm having scope difficulties. 
Any suggestions are welcome!

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
                                        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(this->ui->pushButton_8,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_8_clicked()));
    //connect(this->ui->checkBox_2,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(myInterruptRIGHT));
    //connect(this->ui->checkBox_2,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(myInterruptLEFT));
    // connect(on_checkBox_2_stateChanged(int arg1)(),SIGNAL(clicked(bool checked)),this,SLOT(myInterruptRIGHT));
    ui->pushButton->setText("STOP");


    ui->verticalSlider->setMinimum(6);
    ui->verticalSlider->setMaximum(8);
}

void MainWindow::on_checkBox_2_stateChanged(int arg1)
{
    QCheckBox *cb2 = new QCheckBox;
    connect(cb2,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),this,SLOT(on_checkBox_2_stateChanged(int)));
    int sensor = digitalRead(23);
    //Does a bunch of stuff
}

void myInterruptRIGHT (void)
{
    //if(this->ui->checkBox_2->isChecked())

    if(ui->checkBox_2->isChecked())

    { //Does stuff
    }
    else
    { //more stuff
    }
}


PI_THREAD(RightTop)
{
    for(;;)
    {

        wiringPiISR(23,INT_EDGE_RISING,&myInterruptRIGHT);

    }
}
```

I apologize for the sloppish code, I've been testing a bunch of different things and nothing has proven very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: `MainWindow::on_checkBox_2_stateChanged` creates the checkbox and connects itself to slot of checkbox signal? Make sure the checkbox created somewhere in constructor or maybe in UI pre-designed part of code.

Problem 2: `PI_THREAD` does not seem to be Qt thread to catch a signal on it with the slot. You still can do something about it for your embedded application.

Please note that I of course could not test the solution but I did apply similar techniques in real applications. You may consider `std::atomic<T>` as well.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
     public:
        QAtomicInt& atomicChkBox2State() {return m_chkBox2StateAtomic;}
     //// snip
     private:
        QAtomicInt m_chkBox2StateAtomic;
     //// snip
};


void MainWindow::on_checkBox_2_stateChanged(int state)
{
    m_chkBox2StateAtomic = state;
}


// where you create MainWindow you need to get that pointer somehow

static MainWindow* s_pMainWnd;
MainWindow* getMainWindow() {return s_pMainWnd;} // declare it in the .h file

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    s_pMainWnd = &w; // take an address

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

// and that ISR should read the atomic variable in case if does poll for check:

void myInterruptRIGHT (void)
{
    // now poll the atomic variable reflecting the state of checkbox
    if(getMainWindow()->atomicChkBox2State())

    { //Does stuff
    }
    else
    { //more stuff
    }
}
```

That is for ISR that constantly polling the atomic variable when called by the system interrupt vector. If that Interrupt Service Routine supposed to get very own terminate signal pushed from the checkbox then we cannot answer that without knowing more about your embedded platform "how to terminate the ISR from the 'side' not by system interrupt".

Comment: Ok, so I tried that, and it may be on it's way, but I'm getting 2 similar errors of: 'invalid use of QAtomicInteger' without an argument list'. I figured that for now, I'd just run with what you've thrown out there, and maybe change it up once I get some results.

Comment: Use QAtomicInt and not QAtomicInteger.

Comment: I think the problem might be coming from my declaration (or lack thereof) of the getMainWindow(); in the header file, because when I try to call it in the ISR it is unrecognized. Is there some way I should be referring to it that I'm unaware of?

Comment: M... that is just common C++ knowledge. Both #include "MainWindow.h" and MainWindow* getMainWindow(); should be somewhere on top of file. That hints you have a long way to go to get where you really use Qt for embedded apps.